# Can't Save Collection Field Data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am not able to collection [Purchase Entity] data

My PO Entity --- Create Controller

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new PO();
    $form = $this->createForm(new POType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('po_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

My Form Builder - PO

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('orderno','text',array('attr'=>array
            ('placeholder'=>"Order No",'class'=>'input-medium','pattern'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9]+')))
        ->add('invoiceno','text',array('attr'=>array
            ('placeholder'=>"Invoice No",'class'=>'input-medium','pattern'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9]+')))
        ->add('buyervat','text',array('attr'=>array
            ('placeholder'=>"Buyer VAT No",'class'=>'input-medium')))
        ->add('sellervat','text',array('attr'=>array
            ('placeholder'=>"Seller VAT No",'class'=>'input-medium')))
        ->add('vatamount','number',array('attr'=>array
            ('placeholder'=>"Vat Amount",'class'=>'input-medium','pattern'=>'[0-9]+')))
        ->add('orderdate','date')
        ->add('payment','text',array('attr'=>array
            ('placeholder'=>"Payment Type:Ref No",'class'=>'input-medium',)))
        ->add('credit','number',array('attr'=>array
            ('placeholder'=>"Credit",'class'=>'input-medium',)))
        ->add('note','text',array('attr'=>array
            ('placeholder'=>"Note",'class'=>'input-medium',)))
        ->add('purchases','collection',array(
            'type'=>new PurchaseType(),
            'allow_add'=> true,
            'allow_delete'=>true,
            'by_reference' => false,))
    ;
}
```

Purchase Entity

```
<?php

namespace CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Purchase
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Purchase
{


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PO", inversedBy="purchases")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="po_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $po;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
}

/**
 * Set po
 *
 * @param \CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\PO $po
 * @return Purchase
 */
public function setPo(\CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\PO $po = null)
{
    $this->po = $po;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get po
 *
 * @return \CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\PO 
 */
public function getPo()
{
    return $this->po;
}
}
```

My PO Entity

```
<?php

namespace CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * PO
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class PO
{
...

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Purchase", mappedBy="po", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $purchases;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->purchases =  new ArrayCollection();
    $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
}

/**
 * Add purchases
 *
 * @param \CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\Purchase $purchases
 * @return PO
 */
public function addPurchase(\CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\Purchase $purchases)
{
    $this->purchases[] = $purchases;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove purchases
 *
 * @param \CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\Purchase $purchases
 */
public function removePurchase(\CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\Purchase $purchases)
{
    $this->purchases->removeElement($purchases);
}

/**
 * Get purchases
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPurchases()
{
    return $this->purchases;
}
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass PO object to Purchase objects manually.

Edit the `addPurchase` method as below:

```
public function addPurchase(\CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\Purchase $purchases)
{
    $this->purchases[] = $purchases;
    $purchases->setPo($this);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: should this part have syntax according to an array collection.

Comment: If I adding two purchases to the Po. Only one is getting saved. There is no record of the second purchase. I wanted to do something like whats done for tags out here http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Well, your code is correct and it should work. I suggest you upgrade Symfony to the recent version and read correspoding documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html Also provide us the controller's code

Comment: i am using latest symfony2.2.1. The controller is the same as the one i have mentioned above. I made no changes to it. But I did make changes to the create controller in purchases for some other task. Does that make any difference.according me the po controller has nothing to do with purchase controller. The po controller only works with the entity of purchase

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27921/discussion-between-vadim-ashikhman-and-c-j)

Comment: @vadimashikman I found the issue. If you add two or more purchases with exact same value only one will be added. Otherwise if they are different all are added. Thanks a lot for your help